# Python Flight Distance And Time Calculator

Tags: python, math, calculator, distance, plane

Could someone help me with this code? Currently it displays the error:

> ValueError: Invalid conversion specification

I am unsure on how to solve it. Also, could you tell me how to properly format this code so that it looks more tidy and whether or not I did other things wrong or if other errors will appear?

For testing purposes if you want you could use the two sets of longitudes and latitudes:

```
Latitude: 17.935667
Longitude: -76.7875
```

and

```
Latitude: -34.945
Longitude: 138.530556
```

Here is my code:

```
import math

radius = 6371.01

city1 = raw_input("First city: ")
x1 = float(input("First latitude: "))
y1 = float(input("First longitude: "))
city2 = raw_input("Second City: ")
x2 = float(input("Second latitude: "))
y2 = float(input("Second longitude: "))

def distance(radius, x1, x2, y1, y2):

    d = radius * math.acos(math.sin(x1)*math.sin(x2)+math.cos(x1)*math.cos(x2)*math.cos(abs(y1-y2)))
    return d

distance = distance(radius, x1, x2, y1, y2)

Blackbird = 3230
BombardierCRJ1000 = 870

tbird = distance/3230
tBombardierCRJ1000 = distance/870

cseconds = tBombardierCRJ1000 * 60 * 60 * 60
hctime = cseconds / 3600
cseconds -= 3600*hctime 
mctime = cseconds / 60

hseconds = tbird * 60 * 60 * 60
hhtime = hseconds / 3600
hseconds -= 3600*hhtime 
mhtime =  hseconds / 60

print("Commercial aircraft: Bombardier CRJ 1000 - 870 km/hr")
print("High-Speed aircraft: SR-71 Blackbird - 1354 km/hr")

print("Departure")
print("City            Latitude    Longitude")  
print("{0:s}          {1:.5f}  -  {2:.5f)}" .format(city1, x1, y1))     
print("---------------------------------------------------------------    -------")
print("Destination")
print("City            Latitude    Longitude   Distance Commercial     High-Speed")
print("                                        (km)     Time (h:m)     Time (h:m)")
print("{0:s}     {1:.5f}      {2:.5f}       {3:.2f}       {4:d}:{5:d}     {6:d}:{7:d}" .format(city2, x2,y2, distance, hctime,mctime, hhtime, mhtime))
```

Comment: You should avoid naming your float `distance` as it is the same than the function used to compute it. If you ever want to modify your script to be able to compute more than one value, it might come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your formatting. You should remove `)` from `{2:.5f)}`:

```
print("{0:s}          {1:.5f}  -  {2:.5f}".format(city1, x1, y1)),
```

Comment: Great I totally missed that. I also fixed the following float error by adding int() to the time calculations. Thanks!

Comment: Clicked it! Sorry still new to this haha